# Redirecting a url to an existing server

Tags: apache, url, redirect

I have recently purchased a domain mydomainname.ca for my web mydomainname.com i would like the .ca to redirect to .com. I am very new to setting up web domains and such since my website was previously set up by another person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities and as long as you don't specify the exact deployment, I'll explain all (hopefully) of them:

- if you have only a domain and possibly a dns, route the .ca domain to your webserver, where mydomainname.com is located and then add virtual host alias to your .com webserver configuration
- if you have domain and webhosting and the previous option is not possible (i.e. you don't have access to httpd config), use `HTTP meta-redirect tag` or `Location:` header to redirect to your .com domain

References:

- Apache2 conf: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html
- HTML Meta tag: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh
- PHP header function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: These links were very useful! I had to use a combination of apache2 and PHP to do the trick!